# How could I show invalid validation border on input with a button in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How does Bootstrap handle invalid validation error border on an input (with a button)? From the Bootstrap documentation I [read](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-control-validation) the following:

> Bootstrap includes validation styles for error, warning, and success
>   states on form controls. To use, add `.has-warning`, `.has-error`, or
>   `.has-success` to the parent element. Any `.control-label`, `.form-control`,
>   and `.help-block` within that element will receive the validation
>   styles.

In accordance with any information provided above, I managed the following fiddle:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label for="exampleInput1">Label</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I fix the button's side border?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two conditions to try. If you can use bootstrap simply replace btn-default to `btn-danger` or Create the **border style** and apply it on button

Comment: So there is no solution for this within Bootstrap 3 then, I should come with my own CSS solution (when not using the `btn-danger` method)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it with button and you want the error border to propagate to that button too, you need to add some css.

```
.has-error .input-group-btn{
     border-color: #a94442;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

And it should work, i looked in the bootstrap docs and they use input-group-addon.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 [uses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#input-groups-buttons) `input-group-btn` as well.

Comment: @Barrosy well still they dont support has-error with input-group-btn as child... so my code is not useless

Comment: Oh, I never said it was useless, it's actually quite helpful. I was just pointing out something you missed in your answer. It's actually the only way I could think of fixing the problem as of right now although I am curious why the Bootstrap developers haven't thought of implementing this.

Comment: Me too... this looks like something you would not forget to implement... but its a big system framework and they are just people... im gonna check if they did it in bootstrap 4 or not.. chance to tell them on git :)

Comment: @Barrosy no they dont... it looks exactly same like in B3, i guess they want it that way... because the button is not invalid... only the input is... so thats why maybe

Comment: Even then the border on the right side of the input (left of the button) should at least light up red then, would you not agree?

Comment: well that does on Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this simple solution.

```css
.btn.button-border{
border-color:#a94442;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label for="exampleInput1">Label</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-border" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the css styles to your html, like this:

```
.has-error .input-group-btn > button{
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

In this way you will always get border on your buttons when they are directly childs of class `.input-group-btn`.

Don't forget that you need to create same methodology to the other validations `.has-warning` and `.has-success`.

Any question regarding this, feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label for="exampleInput1">Label</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you using `bootstrap 3.x.x` you need style with additional css. Here is an example:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3m0vrs1/)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to my problem and still keep the input and button separated in accordance with Every Screamer's comment.

Simply adding this to my CSS:

```
.has-error .input-group .form-control, .has-warning.input-group .form-control, .has-success .input-group .form-control {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```css
.has-error .input-group .form-control,
.has-warning.input-group .form-control,
.has-success .input-group .form-control {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label for="exampleInput1">Label</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this will cause and problems/issues and/or bugs, please let me know.